# How to change visual studio collapsed functions

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have rummaged through settings but didn't find anything relevant, so is there an option to change visuals of collapsed functions in visual studio c# editor to look more like vb?

As seen in c#:
[image: c#]

Want it to be more like:
[image: vb]

Comment: You need to put the methods into a class.  c# in a console application the methods have to be static in the class with main.

Comment: @jdweng, static methods are still members of a class. A C# console app project has a class named `Program` by default and that's where the methods are by default.

Comment: Personally i think the C# version is better. just saying. Additionally i have never seen an option to do this

Comment: The answer is "no". I think you'll find that C# collapses based on paired braces and the method declaration is not part of that. You can place braces around any block of code and collapse the whole section. In VB, there are no braces and the block is defined by the opening and closing construct. In that case, the method declaration is part of the block being collapsed.

Comment: You must have static in the Program Class.  To remove the static so it looks like vb.net you would need to put the methods into a new class.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `Regions` as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not achieve that in C# text editor, because only the part within curly braces { } is grayed out, not function name.
Still you can play with fonts and colors - [follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-the-editor?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks, but there is no option to differentiate collapsed function, and other things don't bother me as much (color wise).

Comment: Apply some trick. You can give some bright highlighting color to that gray comment box. This will make them look distinguished, and you can easily avoid collapsed funtions while going through your code.

Answer (score 0):

you have nothing to change, they use what we call a **region**, instead of closing your methods, you can use the region as shown below

```
#region MyClass definition  
public class MyClass   
{  
   static void Main()   
  {   
  }  
}  
#endregion
```

[How To Use Region In Visual Studio / Microsoft DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region)

Comment: Thanks, but I find my c# code to be quite cluttered as is, adding regions would make it even more so. I'm more used to VB, so its harder for me to filter info when collapsed functions are color-coded the same way as active ones.